# jquery image modal not loading image first time

Tags: javascript, jquery

My page (built using wordpress) uses some jquery to show a modal when an image is clicked. The modal contains the image that was clicked and I used the below jquery to do this.

Trouble is that when the page is loaded, the first image click shows the modal but the src of the modal image hasnt been updated with the url of the clicked image.

It looks like the jquery hasnt run. Once the modal is closed and a new image is clicked it works.

The page does have lazy loading but the image says "loaded" in the image tag

Any ideas?

page link: https://www.musiciansforscreen.com/musicians/flavio/

.prof-image is the imafge the user clicks
.lightbox-image is the image in the modal

```
jQuery('.prof-image').click( function() {
  
  var image = jQuery(this).attr('src');
  
  jQuery('.lightbox-image').attr('src', image );
  
});
```

Comment: I can't find above code in your page.

Answer (score 0):

your code does **not run in the first time** and then **it runs in the second time** because the modal **was about "showing" and not "shown" yet** ..
so that's why the ".lightbox-image" will be not used to set your image because it was not loaded yet in the dom (in the first step).
in that case you have to use the "on shown event" of the modal" , after that put your code insde .
look at this [modal events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events)

here is my code solution:

```
var lastImgSrc = null;
/** change #myModal to your modal id **/
jQuery('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        // if the modal is fully loaded and the lastImgSrc is not null, set the src url with the wanted value.
    if(lastImgSrc){
        jQuery('.lightbox-image').attr('src', lastImgSrc ); 
    }
});

jQuery('.prof-image').click( function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  lastImgSrc = jQuery(this).attr('src');
  jQuery('#myModal').modal('show'); // show modal manually
});

jQuery('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  lastImgSrc = null; // if modal closed then reset the variable;
})
```

Comment: apologies I cant make that work but maybe I'm putting the code wrong? could you show an example of how I would modify my code?

Comment: no problem, i will re-edit my code if it still usefull

Answer (score 0):

Ok I actually solved this by updating the code to change the "data-lazy-src" as well as the "src" attribute. The "data-lazy-src" attribute was cueing up the placeholder image so changing that sorted the issue.

Comment: Hello, it's nice solution, but to understand your issue, you can check my [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66492213/8678900) post.